# Passing string rather than function in django url pattern

Tags: python, django, django-urls

In the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#passing-strings-instead-of-callable-objects) it says about url patterns:

> It is possible to pass a string containing the path to a view rather
>   than the actual Python function object. This alternative is supported
>   for the time being, though is not recommended and will be removed in a
>   future version of Django.

Does anyone have any insight as to why this the case? I find this alternative to be quite handy and can't find anything explaining why this is a bad (or, at least, less than ideal) idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the [1.8 Release Notes](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/docs/releases/1.8.txt#L695) in the repo explains it quite well. Here's a summary of the main points:

> In the modern era, we have updated the tutorial to instead recommend importing
>   your views module and referencing your view functions (or classes) directly.
>   This has a number of advantages, all deriving from the fact that we are using
>   normal Python in place of "Django String Magic": the errors when you mistype a
>   view name are less obscure, IDEs can help with autocompletion of view names,
>   etc.
>
> Thus `patterns()` serves little purpose and is a burden when teaching new users
>   (answering the newbie's question "why do I need this empty string as the first
>   argument to `patterns()`?"). For these reasons, we are deprecating it.
>   Updating your code is as simple as ensuring that `urlpatterns` is a list of
>   :func:`django.conf.urls.url` instances.